# QT4 How to use static fields?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I am trying to use static fields in QT

```
class MyLabel:public QLabel{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
  static QPixmap pix1;
  static QPixmap *pix2;
  static int WasInited;
  ...
};

int MyLabel::WasInited = 0;

MyLabel::MyLabel(){
  . . . 
  if (WasInited==0)  pix1.load("pic.png");   // Error
  if (WasInited==0)  pix2->load("pic.png");  // Error
  WasInited=1; // Here using static field is OK

}
```

But i always get "undefined reference to MyLabel::pix*' " error

How do i declare and use static fields of standart QT classes?

P.S. I have no problems using int static fields, so i think my question is QT specific

Comment: I'm retaging your question, because it's more C++ related

Comment: Review your questions, and accept answers. People won't help you if they see that you don't appreciate their help

Comment: I think that problem is still QT specific. I have no problems using static int fields

Comment: It's still more C++ related. You won't get error for int, until you use it. Try adding in your constructor WasInited = 1; Compiler should now yeld about undefined reerence to MyLabel::WasInited

Comment: OK it's really does not matter when problem is solved. But still "You can't create QPixmap without QApplication object. QPixmap internals requires QApplication initialization, therefore they can't be initialized with proper value before first use of QApplication." meens that QT specific here does matter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

static fields are like methods in a class. First you need to declare them, then you need to define their initial value.

With QPixmaps it's a little bit different. As static members are initialized before main entry point. QPixmap requires QApplication to work, so you won't be able to make it static as variable, you may however make it static as pointers. You need also to "define" a static member. By definining you declare it's initial value. In both cases it HAS to be NULL, because you still can't create QPixmap. Inside constructor of your class you may check if pointers are NULL, and if yes then you can initialize them with proper values.

Comment: If you would like to edit your answer to include general information for initializing statics and the exceptional case for QPixmaps, I'll delete my answer so it's all in one place.